# What is the correct form after "as well as"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, conjugation

What is the correct form after as well as?

> App lets you send free messages (SMS, MMS, location-sharing) as well as **make** free calls to other App users on iPhone.

or

> App lets you send free messages (SMS, MMS, location-sharing) as well as **making** free calls to other App users on iPhone.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The structures before and after "as well as" should be parallel, so your first example is correct and your second is not. To test, check the parts independently: "App lets you send something" and "App lets you make something" both make sense, but "App lets you making something" does not.

Comment: @JEL, you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

LET is one of those verbs that take bare-infinitives after them. 'AS WELL AS'  is a mode of saying 'AND' forcefully. So, 'send' & 'make' are used without 'TO'. First sentence is grammatical.

Now let us examine two other sentences:

° I saw Jill dance.

° I saw Jill dancing.

These to sentences are an extension of the rule enumerated above and the verb 'SEE' belongs to the same group of 'LET'; They can take either bare infinitive or participle.

By this  argument your last sentence is also correct. But whether you are to change 'send' to 'sending' and that too, without losing beauty of the sentence or keep it as it is now, you have to decide yourself. The last sentence doesn't flout any grammatical rules, this much we can vouch.

Answer (score -2):

Making seems to be grammatically in correct. Substitute the 'as well as' with another conjunction eg 'and'. You will find that the first sentence is correct.